# create a matrix from combinations with values

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I have some combinations like

```
(A,B) = 1
(A,C) = 0
(A,D) = 1
(B,C) = 1
(B,D) = 1
(C,D) = 0
```

Any idea on how I efficiently can create a four by four matrix with these 0,1 values from all these combinations? So the result will be something like:

```
  A B C D
A - 1 0 1
B 1 - 1 1
C 0 1 - 0
D 1 1 0 -
```

Comment: Is the diagonal of your matrix just zeroes? Also what have you tried, do you have a working solution and are just looking for a faster way? If so, please include it.

Comment: how are those combinations stored?

Comment: yes diagonal can be zeroes! I couldn't think of any viable solution!

Comment: The combinations are stored in text file.

Comment: Note that a matrix in python, in its simplest form, can be thought of as a list of lists. Here, it is a list which contains 4 lists of length 4: each of these 4 lists is a row. You can see numpy for some actual matrix structures as well, which may help you build it faster.

Comment: if they are stored in a file: how precisely is the format?

Comment: There isn't any working code here or even any unambiguous representations of the output. Please fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine if the "combinations" are stored in a file in the following format (or similar):

```
A,B,1
A,C,0
A,D,1
B,C,1
B,D,1
C,D,0
```

Then you can do:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
```

Example (using your sample data):

```py
txt = """A,B,1
A,C,0
A,D,1
B,C,1
B,D,1
C,D,0
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), header=None)
```

Now `df` contains:

```
   0  1  2
0  A  B  1
1  A  C  0
2  A  D  1
3  B  C  1
4  B  D  1
5  C  D  0
```

From that point, a little bit of massaging will get you what you want:

```py
# all labels (for rows and cols)
r = sorted(set(df[0]) | set(df[1]))

# upper triangular
z = (
    df.set_index([0, 1])
    .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([r, r]))
    .squeeze()
    .unstack(1)
)

# fill in the lower triangular part to make z symmetric
z = z.where(~z.isna(), z.T)
```

We get:

```py
>>> z
     A    B    C    D
A  NaN  1.0  0.0  1.0
B  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
C  0.0  1.0  NaN  0.0
D  1.0  1.0  0.0  NaN
```

Note: if you prefer to stay in `int`-only (and set the diagonal to 0), then:

```py
z = (
    df.set_index([0, 1])
    .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([r, r]), fill_value=0)
    .squeeze()
    .unstack(1)
)
z += z.T
```

and now:

```py
>>> z
   A  B  C  D
A  0  1  0  1
B  1  0  1  1
C  0  1  0  0
D  1  1  0  0
```

**For speed**

Now, if you know for sure that you are dealing with 4x4 matrices and that the order is exactly as you indicated (ordered by the upper triangle), you can do the following for a faster set up:

```py
# get the triangular values, somehow (e.g. read file and discard
# all but the last value;

# here we simply take them from the df above:
tri = df[2].values  # np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])

# and now, in pure numpy:
z = np.zeros((4,4), dtype=int)
z[np.triu_indices(4, 1)] = tri
z += z.T
```

The result is a simple `numpy` array (no labels):

```py
>>> z
[[0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with a pivot operation.  Let's say your combinations come in a csv file that looks like this (they could just as easily come in some data structure such as a dictionary or 2D list):

```
A,B,1
A,C,0
A,D,1
B,C,1
B,D,1
C,D,0
A,A
B,B
C,C
D,D
```

Then you can do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ['col1','col2', 'value']

df = df.pivot(index='col1',columns='col2',values='value')
df =df.where(~df.isna(), df.T) #reflects half-matrix across diagonal
df.fillna('-', inplace=True)

print(df)

#output:
col2  A  B  C  D
col1            
A     -  1  0  1
B     1  -  1  1
C     0  1  -  0
D     1  1  0  -
```